# Is a devotee of lord Hanuman required to maintain his chastity?

Tags: hanuman

I usually feel guilty when I feel attracted towards a girl due to the fact that I'm a hanuman bhakt.

As from what I've heard from my elders that Hanuman bhakts are required to maintain their chastity atleast until they get married.

Comment: This is where knowledge helps to cross these attractions. Attraction is not true because we are attracted not only to one girl or boy, many which means this is just facial attractions, and sometimes one gets attracted to a girl because of her Guna, these are all just a play and attraction reflection of mind. What happens if this need is fullfilled? Yes temporary happiness but one day you will realize her character isnt good despite attraction and you cant live further anymore. So what will happen then? So use your buddhi, and overcome these....I am talking of how today we are weak mentally!

Comment: You are asking about Bhakti (devotion) towards Sri Hanuman.  Devotion to a particular deity is the beginning stage for further stages in spirituality.  As far as I know, maintaining Chastity, is sine qua non, only for practicing towards spirituality.   Attraction towards opposite sex is quite but NATURAL in young age.  Unless you are aspiring for serious SPIRITUAL practices, feel relieved of your anguish about your attraction towards opposite sex and continue with your Bhakti   towards Sri Hanuman.